# WCF call Java SOAP service - namespace issue

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm working on really light and small project about SOAP connection between WCF client and JAX-WS service. I will simplify problem as i can, that i will use fake things. Assume i have WS service:

```
@WebService(serviceName="Example", targetNamespace="http://please.help.me/")
public class SimpleService {
    @WebMethod(operationName="exampleOp")
    public String exampleOp(@WebParam(name="example", targetNamespace="http://please.help.me/") String example) {
        return "Do nothing";
    }
}
```

Ok, so WSDL file is generated (important thing from it is):

```
<xs:complexType name="exampleOp">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="example" type="xs:string" />
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

And i generate C# file using svcutil.exe from WSDL, that gives me:

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://please.help.me/", Order=0)]
public string example;
```

And after it if i call this method, the message from client looks like that:

```
<exampleOp xmlns="http://please.help.me">
    <example>Blah blah blah</example>
</exampleOp>
```

But only what java accepts (it's qualified form, for God sake!):

```
<exampleOp xmlns="http://please.help.me" xmlns:d="http://please.help.me">
    <d:example>Blah blah blah</example>
</exampleOp>
```

How i can force one of sides to communicate clearly with qualified names? Please.

Comment: You might need to implement IClientInspector to satisfy the picky Java Web service.

Comment: I'm already using it to adding soap headers. But i hope there is less complicated solution.

Comment: maybe adopt this approach to the request: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/06/13/changing-prefixes-in-xml-responses.aspx